# Issue deploying Rails App to Heroku, tiny_tds fails to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku-cli

I'm trying to deploy an app to Heroku and keep getting the following error with tiny_tds, does anyone have experience with this?

```
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.2.0/tiny_tds-2.1.5/mkmf.log
remote:
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.5 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.2.0/tiny_tds-2.1.5/gem_make.out
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:119:in
remote:        `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:27:in
remote:        `build'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:187:in
remote:        `build_extension'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:221:in
remote:        `block in build_extensions'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:218:in
remote:        `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:218:in
remote:        `build_extensions'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:843:in
remote:        `build_extensions'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
remote:        `build_extensions'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
remote:        `install'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in
remote:        `install'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
remote:        `install'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
remote:        `install_from_spec'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:156:in
remote:        `do_install'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:147:in
remote:        `block in worker_pool'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
remote:        `apply_func'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
remote:        `block in process_queue'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
remote:        `loop'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
remote:        `process_queue'
remote:        /tmp/build_188016fe/vendor/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/worker.rb:90:in
remote:        `block (2 levels) in create_threads'
remote:
remote:        An error occurred while installing tiny_tds (2.1.5), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:          activerecord-sqlserver-adapter was resolved to 7.0.4.0, which depends on
remote:            tiny_tds
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

I've run this command: `heroku buildpacks:set --index 1`  https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/heroku-buildpack-freetds

But then app crashes

```
2023-10-27T01:28:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-10-27T01:28:37.022446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-10-27T01:28:37.167272+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-10-27T01:28:37.568711+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 11083`
2023-10-27T01:28:37.622486+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -q default`
2023-10-27T01:28:38.209004+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-10-27T01:28:38.282602+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: line 1: bundle: command not found
2023-10-27T01:28:38.309459+00:00 app[worker.1]: bash: line 1: bundle: command not found
2023-10-27T01:28:38.414968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-10-27T01:28:38.445135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-10-27T01:28:38.451320+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-10-27T01:28:38.482151+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```